# Update Row using SqlDataAdapter not working

Tags: c#, sql

I wrote this function for updating one single row (I store the information in a class T):

```
public void Update(T model)
{
    if (!Exist(model))
    {
        throw new Exception("Object Not Found");
    }
    DataRow row = Convert(model);
    row.Table.Rows.Add(row);
    row.AcceptChanges();
    row.SetModified();
    _dataAdapter.Update(new[] { row });
}
```

(The DataRow comes detached)

the SqlDataAdapter is configured as so:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From " + tableName, 
        ConnectedDAL.GetConnection());
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
```

For some reason my insert and delete work, but the update does not.
The call to Update() completes without errors but the database does not receive the updates.

Help?

**Update**

The update command text from the command builder is wierd:

For cities (CityID, CityName, CountryID)

"Update [Cities] Set [CityName] = @p1, [CountryID] = @p2 WHERE (([CityID] = @p3 AND ([CityName] = @p4) AND ([CountryID] = @p5))

The first condition makes sense but the rest don't. Also the call returns 1, meaning the it thinks it made the changes.

Comment: Does it have the right primary key? Use the debugger

Comment: So `Convert` assigns a `Table` to the row? What is the point of adding the row to the row's table? Anyway, did you Trace the database to see what if anything is running?

Comment: See CommandBuilder : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx  For an update to work you need four commands in your SQL Command : Select, Update, Insert, Delete.  The command builder will take a Select command and automatically build the other 3.

Comment: @jdweng I think OP knows this. Notice the select command, the command builder, and the fact that insert and deletes work.

Comment: @Crowcoder The convert takes my model and a new row from the correct table and puts the data in. The idea is then to set the row up so it will perform the correct action, in this case update.

Comment: @Tim Wouldn't the delete not work if the keys are not set up correctly?

Comment: @tjw: you're right, shouldnt work either

Comment: Is there any difference if you do this: `_dataAdapter.Update(row.Table)` ?

Comment: If you do not want to use the command builder you would have to add all four commands in SQL Command to do exactly what you want.  The update will not work without four commands loaded.

Comment: @jdweng I want to use the command builder because otherwise this service class wont work with all of my tables dynamically... I do want to use it.

Comment: @Crowcoder The _dataAdapter.Update(row.Table) didn't change anything.

Comment: The update method returns an integer indicating the number of rows changed.  If the returned value is zero it means that no rows got updated.  It will not insert data, so when the updated returns zero you must issue the change again using the insert method.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to make it work.

```
public void Update(T model)
{
    if (!Exist(model))
    {
        throw new Exception("Object Not Found");
    }

    DataRow tmp = GetRow(model);
    _dataAdapter.Update(new []{ tmp });
}

private DataRow GetRow(T model)
{
    DataRow row = Convert(model);
    var schem = Schema;
    string[] keys = new string[schem.PrimaryKey.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < schem.PrimaryKey.Length; i++)
    {
        DataColumn column = schem.PrimaryKey[i];
        keys[i] = row[column.ColumnName].ToString();
    }
    DataRow dr = Convert(Select(keys));
    dr.Table.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr.AcceptChanges();
    for (var i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!schem.Columns[i].AutoIncrement)
        {
            dr[i] = row.ItemArray[i];
        }
    }
    return dr;
 }
```

This works.